# iOS app crashing due to memory error

Tags: ios, iphone, memory

My app keeps crashing due to memory error, and I can't figure out why.  The instruments tool is telling me that the memory is getting up to 70mb, but when I try to look at whats being allocated its just a lot of small malloc's, on the order of a few kilobytes max.

It seems like my problem is this snippet of code, where when a slider is moved, the overlay on the map is removed and a new one is drawn and added to the map.  If i keep moving the slider back and forth for about 20 seconds, thats when i get a memory warning and then my app crashes soon after.

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
shouldCenterMap = YES;


 if (fabs(_slider.value - prevSliderVal) >.1) {
    CGPoint nePoint = CGPointMake(self.mapView.bounds.origin.x + (_mapView.bounds.size.width+_mapView.bounds.size.width*_slider.value)/2, _mapView.bounds.origin.y);
    CGPoint nwPoint = CGPointMake(self.mapView.bounds.origin.x + (_mapView.bounds.size.width - _mapView.bounds.size.width*_slider.value)/2, _mapView.bounds.origin.y);




    //Then transform those point into lat,lng values
    points[0] = [_mapView convertPoint:nePoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];

    points[1] = centerPoint;
    points[2] = centerPoint;
    //points[1] = [_mapView convertPoint:sePoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];
    //points[2] = [_mapView convertPoint:swPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];

    points[3] = [_mapView convertPoint:nwPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mapView];

    [_mapView removeOverlay:poly];
    poly = [[MKPolygon alloc] init];
    poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
    [_mapView addOverlay:poly];
    prevSliderVal = _slider.value;
 }
}
```

Is there any way to figure out exactly whats causing this problem? I think it might be something with the overlays not being released properly.

**EDIT: 
Poly is declared just under implementation as: `MKPolygon *poly;`**

**I'm assuming I am using ARC because I'm using XCode 5 and it gives me errors if I try to autorelease anything.**

### **EDIT 2: Could it be the case that my app is crashing not because of live memory usage, but because it is deallocating and reallocating overlays and the total memory usage is too high?  Instruments seems to tell me that it hovers around about 40mb-60mb of live memory usage at any one time.**

Comment: Where and how is `poly` declared?

Comment: *"just under implementation as: MKPolygon *poly;"* So it's a global, not a property of the class or an instance variable?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, so that it can be accessed by all the methods.  Should I put it in curly braces to make it an instance variable? (sorry, I'm stuck in the Java syntax and just found out how to create instance variables like this)

Comment: As far as memory management goes, it probably doesn't matter. As far as having well designed software goes, yes, definitely make this a `@property` of the class.

Comment: Regarding edit 2: If you're already using Instruments and the allocation tool, you can find out what memory allocations are causing the problem. That's what I would do at this point if it were my app.

Comment: @TomHarrington how do I do that? Its just showing me a bunch of `malloc`'s and not one huge chunk, and I'm not sure where to find where these `malloc`'s are being called

Answer (score 0):

The only suspicious part in your code might be the `MKPolygon` `poly`. Post code where you declare it?

You can also try running **`Leaks`** instrument to spot potential memory leaks in your code.

[Instruments Tutorial for iOS: How To Debug Memory Leaks](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks)

Comment: I ran the leaks instrument and got nothing.

The poly variable is declared right under `@implementation` :
`MKPolygon *poly;`
and then its initialized in another method for the first time with the same code thats at the end of my method above.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using ARC, here's a straightforward leak:

```
poly = [[MKPolygon alloc] init];
poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
```

I bet that the static analyser doesn't like this and tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Before, I didn't have the "poly = [[MKPolygon alloc] init];" line and it still used up a lot of memory.  I added that line in there to try to deallocate the previous poly variable in case it was still holding onto it.